# Non Mutually Exclusive events

Tags: probability-theory

Having been reprimanded for posting a question on the wrong site, I hope I'm not transgressing this time. In the addition rule for non mutually exclusive events $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ , while $P(A\cap B)$ can be determined by observation, why cannot it always be calculated from $P(A) \cdot  P(B)$?

Example: A lottery box contains 50 lottery tickets numbered 1 to 50. If a lottery ticket is drawn at random, what is the probability that the number drawn is a multiple of 3 or 5? $P(X ∪ Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X ∩ Y)$
Therefore,

$P(X U Y) = 8/25 + 1/5 - 3/50
= (16 + 10 -3)/50$

$= 23/50$

But using $P(X ∩ Y) = P(X) \cdot  P(Y) = 8/25 \cdot  1/5 = 8/(25 \cdot  5) = 8/125$  which is NOT $3/50$?

There are situations where $P(X ∩ Y) = P(X) x P(Y)$ works perfectly, but not in others.

Thank you.

Comment: The product rule works if $X$ and $Y$ are independent. But the number drawn is "divisible by 3" and is "divisible by 5" are not independent events.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent then $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)\cdot P(Y|X)$

$P(X)=\frac8{25}$

The favorable outcomes of $X$ are $3,6,9,12,\color{blue}{15},18,21,24,27,\color{blue}{30},33,36,39,42,\color{blue}{45},48$

The number of outcomes of $X$ is $16$.

Three of them are divisible by $5$. Thus $P(Y|X)=\frac{3}{16}$

Therefore $P(X\cap Y)=\frac8{25}\cdot \frac{3}{16}=\frac3{50}$